# Why jQuery plugin (Tags Input) does not work?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC form with some textboxes. I wanted to add jQuery plugin to create tags. I added it to my project and I selected one of these textboxes ("Keyword") with my jQuery selector.

And I used one of the functions of this plugin ("tagsinput").

As you guessed, I like to create a tag when the user press enter.

I discovered that jQuery files have been added perfectly, but why does this plugin not work?

This is my form:

```
@model MvcInternetShopp.ViewModels.Admin.ProductVm

@{
     ViewBag.Title = "AddProduct";
}

<h2>AddProduct</h2>

<div class="block grid12">
    <div class="breadcrumb">
        <a href="index-2.html">صفحه اصلی</a><span>›</span><a 
href="#">افزودن گروه</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="full9">
    <div class="block grid9">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

           <h1 class="block-header">افزودن گروه</h1>
           <div class="separator"></div>

           <div class="block-standard">
                <div class="form inline">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Product</legend>
                        <div class="group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.product.Name, new 
{ @class = "label" })
                            <div class="controls">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => 
model.product.Name, new { @class = "text" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => 
model.product.Name)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.product.GroupId, 
new { @class = "label" })
                            <div class="controls">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => 
    model.product.GroupId, new { @class = "text" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => 
model.product.GroupId)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => 
model.product.Description, new { @class = "label" })
                            <div class="controls">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => 
model.product.Description, new { @class = "text" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => 
model.product.Description)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.product.Keyword, 
new { @class = "label" })
                            <div class="controls">
                                <div id="t">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => 
model.product.Keyword, new { @class = "text",id="Keyword" })
                                    @*<input type="text" name="tags" 
placeholder="Tags" class="tm-input" />*@
                                </div>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.product.Like, new 
{ @class = "label" })
                            <div class="controls">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => 
 model.product.Like, new { @class = "text" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => 
   model.product.Like)
                              </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.product.DisLike, 
new { @class = "label" })
                        <div class="controls">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => 
model.product.DisLike, new { @class = "text" })
                                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => 
model.product.DisLike)
                            </div>
                         </div>
                        <div class="group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.product.URL, new { 
@class = "label" })
                            <div class="controls">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.product.URL, 
   new { @class = "text" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => 
    model.product.URL)
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="group">
                             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.product.Enable, 
new { @class = "label" })
                            <div class="controls">

                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => 
model.product.Enable, new { @class = "text" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => 
model.product.Enable)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.product.Mojood, 
new { @class = "label" })
                            <div class="controls">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => 
model.product.Mojood, new { @class = "text" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => 
model.product.Mojood)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.product.Tags, new 
{ @class = "label" })
                            <div class="controls">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => 
model.product.Tags, new { @class = "text" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.product.Image, new 
{ @class = "label" })
                            <div class="controls">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => 
model.product.Image, new { @class = "text" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => 
model.product.Image)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="group">
                           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.product.Summery, 
new { @class = "label" })
                            <div class="controls">

                                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => 
model.product.Summery, new { @class = "text", id = "txtSum" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => 
model.product.Summery) 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.product.Price, new 
{ @class = "label" })
                            <div class="controls">

                               @Html.TextBoxFor(model => 
model.product.Price, new { @class = "text", id = "txtPrice" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => 
 model.product.Price)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p>
                            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
                        </p>
                        <textarea id="e">jg</textarea>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@section Styles{
<link href="~/Scripts/TagsInput/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Scripts/Powerful-Lightweight-jQuery-Tag-Management-Plugin-
tagEditor/jquery.tag-editor.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>

    <script src="~/scripts/ckeditor/styles.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/CkEditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/autonumeric/jquery-price.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/TagsInput/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-tagsinput-latest/dist/bootstrap-
tagsinput.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    //
        CKEDITOR.replace('txtSum');
        $(function () {
            $("#Keyword").keypress(function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }).tagsinput();
        });
    </script>
    }
```

Please help me

Comment: Are there any errors you get in browser console especially in this line: `$("#Keyword").keypress(...).tagsinput();`?

Comment: yes!there are .it says:Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:21239/Scripts/bootstrap-tagsinput-latest/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js”

Comment: Have you disabled browser plugins which potentially block scripts (e.g. Adblock Plus etc.)? Did script problem occurs in all browsers or just a single browser? I see you've loading `bootstrap-
tagsinput.min.js` twice using `<script>` tag in `@section Scripts` part, remove the second redundant one.

Comment: no i have not disabled that and i don't use  adblock plus or something.i have firefox and google chrome  and the plugin does not work in neither firefox nor chrome. i removed the second redundant tagsinput,but it does not work yet

Comment: my error changed now.it says tagsinput is not function .oh my god!

Comment: "tagsinput is not function" => are you sure all dependencies of `bootstrap- tagsinput.min.js` included with `<script>` tags? Check if you have redundant call of certain JS files or forgot to add some dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that.

i used bundles in my layout("~/bundles/jquery") and I also used jQuery-3.2.1 in form page.

i deleted my bundle and it worked